# Django production server locally test in windows

Tags: django, windows, server

How to configure a django project for production level in windows. I can't find out how to serve static and media files when DEBUG=False and how to work with gunicorn and nginx in windows. I want to test the project in production level before deploy on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

You have nginx in your pc? if you have, define `STATIC_ROOT` and comment/delete the `STATICFILES_DIRS` definition.
For example:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and in the nginx:

```
location /static/ {    
    autoindex on;    
    root   {your project root};    
}
```